# How to unify 2 scripts of the same type, in order not to create conflict?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following javascript to type portions of code basing on the visitors' browser language.

But I've noticed that the fact that both JS use the same commands (just different conditions) cause a conflict, so only the first listed one will work correctly.

How can I solve this?

```
<script>
const modifyElHTML = (elID, phrases) => {
const el = document.getElementById(elID);
let phrase;
if (italian) {phrase = phrases.italian; }
else if (french) {phrase = phrases.french; }
else if (german) {phrase = phrases.german; }
else {phrase = phrases.english; }
el.innerHTML = `${phrase}`;  };
modifyElHTML('comentario', {italian: 'Scrivi un commento...', french: 'Ajouter un commentaire...', german: 'Kommentieren ...', english: 'Write an answer...',});
</script>   
    
<script>
const modifyElHTML = (elID, phrases) => {
const el = document.getElementById(elID);
let phrase;
if (italian) {phrase = phrases.italian; }
else if (french) {phrase = phrases.french; }
else if (german) {phrase = phrases.german; }
else {phrase = phrases.english; }
el.innerHTML = `<button class="_1gl3 _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft" type="submit" value="1"><span>${phrase}</span></button><a href="#" onclick="exit_alert()"></a>`;  };
modifyElHTML('showmorecomments', {
italian: 'Carica altri 10 commenti', french: 'Chargez 10 autres avis', german: '10 weitere Kommentare laden', english: 'Load 10 more comments',});
</script>
```

Comment: You can add one param into function choise which one must run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just worried about conflicting variable names, you can use a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))... or in JS lingo, an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```js
(function(){
  const modifyElHTML = (elID, phrases) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(elID);
  let phrase;
  if (italian) {phrase = phrases.italian; }
  else if (french) {phrase = phrases.french; }
  else if (german) {phrase = phrases.german; }
  else {phrase = phrases.english; }
  el.innerHTML = `${phrase}`;  };
  modifyElHTML('comentario', {italian: 'Scrivi un commento...', french: 'Ajouter un commentaire...', german: 'Kommentieren ...', english: 'Write an answer...',});
})();

(function(){
  const modifyElHTML = (elID, phrases) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(elID);
  let phrase;
  if (italian) {phrase = phrases.italian; }
  else if (french) {phrase = phrases.french; }
  else if (german) {phrase = phrases.german; }
  else {phrase = phrases.english; }
  el.innerHTML = `<button class="_1gl3 _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft" type="submit" value="1"><span>${phrase}</span></button><a href="#" onclick="exit_alert()"></a>`;  };
  modifyElHTML('showmorecomments', {
  italian: 'Carica altri 10 commenti', french: 'Chargez 10 autres avis', german: '10 weitere Kommentare laden', english: 'Load 10 more comments',});
})();
```

Comment: Not very DRY :)

Comment: @mplungjan - yeah, in practice your method is better, I was just trying ot demonstrate a closure in the simplest way possible.

Comment: thanks a lot... that's exactly what I was lookin for (without changing the style)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter to show a button or a text

```js
let lang;
// lang = "italian"; // shorter than italian = true etc

const modifyElHTML = (elID, phrases, button) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(elID);
  const phrase = phrases[lang||"english"]; // added default language if lang not set
  
  el.innerHTML = button ?  `<button class="_1gl3 _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft" type="submit" value="1"><span>${phrase}</span></button><a href="#" onclick="exit_alert()"></a>` : `${phrase}`;
};

modifyElHTML('comentario', {
  italian: 'Scrivi un commento...',
  french: 'Ajouter un commentaire...',
  german: 'Kommentieren ...',
  english: 'Write an answer...',
});


modifyElHTML('showmorecomments', {
  italian: 'Carica altri 10 commenti',
  french: 'Chargez 10 autres avis',
  german: '10 weitere Kommentare laden',
  english: 'Load 10 more comments',
}, true); // button = true
```

```html
<div id="comentario"></div>
<div id="showmorecomments"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative method. Even tho I don't need buttons. That's anyway a pretty good solution as well.

Comment: Your script had a button. I strongly recommend my method since it cuts down on code you have to modify and debug